# Regex for finding valid filename

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I want to check whether a string is a file name (name DOT ext) or not.

Name of file cannot contain `/ ? * : ; { } \`

Could you please suggest me the regex expression to use in preg_match()?

Comment: Consider that `foobar` or `.htaccess` is a valid filename too.

Comment: Windows or *nix? POSIX standard allows everything except `NUL` and `/`.

Comment: Also, Windows files can't contain `| " < >` and can contain `{ }`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here you go:

```
"[^/?*:;{}\\]+\\.[^/?*:;{}\\]+"
```

"One or more characters that aren't any of these ones, then a dot, then some more characters that aren't these ones."

(As long as you're sure that the dot is really required - if not, it's simply: `"[^/?*:;{}\\]+"`

Comment: @Richie, do you really need the second backslash just before the dot separator? shouldn't it be ...}\\\]+\.[^/?....

Comment: @Rob Wells: It is necessary since PHP strings use the backslash as an escape character as well. "\\" in a PHP string is translated to "\" in the regex. That "\." is translated to "\." is a coincidence resulting from the fact that "\." has no meaning to PHP and is therefore left unchanged. Nontheless it is sloppy not to escape the backslash.

Comment: error coming. might be my mistake, please see
I entered
        $page_regex = "[[^/?*:;{}\\]+\\.[^/?*:;{}\\]+";

        $len  = $this->REQ_URI_PATH_E_LEN; //length of $this->REQ_URI_PATH_E_LEN given below

        $page = $this->REQ_URI_PATH_E[$len - 1]; //holds path elements like 0=>posts, 1=>hello, 2=>newp.php for localhost/posts/hello/newp.php?id=3

        if(preg_match($page_regex,$page)) echo "page";
        else echo "Folder";

error is "Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending matching delimiter ']' found in *line*"

I might be wrong with the syntax, please correct me.

Comment: You have two opening brackets right at the start of the string: "[[

Comment: sorry probably typo
but "[^/?*:;{}\\]+\\.[^/?*:;{}\\]+" is what i entered and it gave the error. Copied it now straight from your answer to this comment and my code as well
:(

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape the forward slashes: [^\/?*:;{}\\]+\\.[^\/?*:;{}\\]+

Comment: no luck. but $page_regex is showing [^\/?*:;{}\]+\.[^\/?*:;{}\]+ on echo.
gawd. this regex mumbo jumbo is getting on mah nerves

Comment: even [^/?*:;{}\\]+\\.[^/?*:;{}\\] doen't work.
whats the + at the end for (in your answer)?

Comment: + means "one or more".  I suggest you write a self-contained failing example and post that, and the errors you're getting, in a new question.

Comment: `"[^/?*:;{}\\]+"` can be dangerous in some cases, cause it validates filename like `.` or `..`

Comment: Why did you not include delimiters? `/^[^\/\?\*:;{}\\\]+\.[^\/\?\*:;{}\\\]+$/`

Comment: @GajusKuizinas: Because the delimiters aren't a part of the regular expression itself.

Answer (score 6):

```
$a = preg_match('=^[^/?*;:{}\\\\]+\.[^/?*;:{}\\\\]+$=', 'file.abc');

^ ... $ - begin and end of the string
[^ ... ] - matches NOT the listed chars.
```

Comment: to allows files without extensions use: `preg_match('=^[^/?*;:{}\\\\]+\.?[^/?*;:{}\\\\]?$=', 'file.abc');`

Answer (score 2):

The regex would be something like (for a three letter extension):

```
^[^/?*:;{}\\]+\.[^/?*:;{}\\]{3}$
```

PHP needs backslashes escaped, and `preg_match()` needs forward slashes escaped, so:

```
$pattern = "/^[^\\/?*:;{}\\\\]+\\.[^\\/?*:;{}\\\\]{3}$/";
```

To match filenames like `"hosts"` or `".htaccess"`, use this slightly modified expression:

```
^[^/?*:;{}\\]*\.?[^/?*:;{}\\]+$
```

Comment: You can of course you something other than "/" to delimit the regex in preg_match(), this removes the need to escape forward slashes specifically, but adds the need to escape the new delimiter character (if you want to use it in the regex).

Comment: Warning ! A filename like `.` or `..` can be dangerous in some case, and is valid with `^[^/?*:;{}\\]*\.?[^/?*:;{}\\]+$`

Answer (score 1):

Below the regex using for checking Unix filename in a Golang program :

```
    reg := regexp.MustCompile("^/[[:print:]]+(/[[:print:]]+)*$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to use solution with specific file extensions:

```
$file = 'file-name_2020.png';
$extensions = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'svg');
$pattern = '/^[^`~!@#$%^&*()+=[\];\',.\/?><":}{]+\.(' . implode('|', $extensions). ')$/u';

if(preg_match($pattern, $discount)) {
    // Returns true
}
```

Keep in mind that special characters allowed in this scenario are only `-` and `_`. To allow more, just remove them from `$pattern`